# matriz donde dibujas diagonales con extremos Lenguaje Java

Tags: java, bucle-for, matrices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public class ChivasLocas {

```
  public void grafChivas(String matr[][]){
      String cadena,coorXY[];
      cadena = sc.nextLine();
      coorXY = cadena.split(" ");
      for (int i = 1; i < coorXY.length; i+=2) {
          matr[ Integer.parseInt(coorXY[i]) ][ Integer.parseInt(coorXY[i+1]) ] = "1";
      }
      imprMatrizStr(matr);
      grafRejas(matr);
  }
  public void grafRejas(String matr[][]){
      String noCaso, coorCasos, coorCasoArr[];
      //noCaso = sc.nextLine();

          coorCasos = sc.nextLine();
          coorCasoArr = coorCasos.split(" ");

          for (int j = 1; j < coorCasoArr.length; j+=2) {
              matr[ Integer.parseInt(coorCasoArr[j]) ][ Integer.parseInt(coorCasoArr[j+1]) ] = "2";
          }

      imprMatrizStr(matr);
  }
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En un corral dónde hay varias chivas peleoneras, un granjero ciego compró rejas para poder separar a cada una y evitar peleas, pero no está seguro sobre la ubicación de las rejas que tiene que armar en el corral para separarlas. Las rejas sólo se pueden colocar en sentido diagonal en el corral. Antes de poner las rejas, el granjero amarra a las chivas al suelo con cordel y estacas para que no se muevan, pero esto sólo es temporal y obviamente no puede colocar las rejas en el lugar que ocupan las chivas. Una vez colocadas las rejas el granjero debe asegurarse que cada sección del corral contiene sólo una chiva antes de soltarlas.
> Entrada
> El archivo de entrada contiene en el primer renglón el tamaño de la matriz de M renglones y N columnas (dónde 1<=M<=10 y 1<=N<=10), en el segundo renglón está el número X de chivas en el corral (donde 1<=X<=5) seguido de las coordenadas por renglón y columna de cada chiva separados por un espacio. En el tercer renglón se especifica el número de casos de rejas para comprobar si aíslan o no a las chivas. Cada renglón siguiente contiene un caso que comienza con el número de rejas a colocar seguido de los pares ordenados (renglón, columna) inicial y final de cada reja, que también están separados por un espacio.
> Salida
> La salida a consola debe imprimir un SI por cada configuración exitosa y un NO por cada caso erróneo.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado y dale un formato correcto a tu pregunta para que se entienda el ejemplo que pones

Comment: Agrega tu codigo Java, el que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor, de favor

Comment: ok ahorita lo agrego mejor

Comment: Listo ya modifique la pregunta espero me puedan ayudar